# ¿Como migrar una base de datos sql server 2008 r2 a sql server 2019?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola buenas tardes como indica mi pregunta me gustaria saber como puedo realizar esta actualización por ahora solo he actualizado mi management studio, pero no puedo ver la base de datos de mi sql server 2008 r2 actualizada en el nuevo sql,quisiera si pudieran darme alguna documentación de como realizar esto.

Comment: ¿Esto es para un sistema de producción o para uso personal?

Comment: Uhmmm... Cuando buscaste en goole, qué palabras utilizaste? Yo obtuve resultados de la documentación oficial [buscando con estos keywords](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=Upgrade+to+sql+server+2019)

Comment: Hola es para produccion es una base que ya estaba antes de que yo llegara y me pidieron que si podia actualizarla a sql server 2019, pero antes de hacer eso quiero probar en mi equipo personal para cuando vaya a hacer la migración evitar errores.

Comment: Y lo que busque en google fue como migrar un sql server 2008 r2 a sql server 2019,y vi que toca actualizar progresivamente es decir del 2008 a el 2012 , 2016,2019 pero quiero hacer primero con una base de pruebas en mi computador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen 2 opciones posibles: Actualizar en la misma instancia o actualizar en otra instancia.

Actualizar en la misma instancia es un proceso que llega a ser peligroso y tardado. Esto es porque necesitas dejar las bases de datos inaccesibles mientras actualizas. Además, tienes que actualizar en 2 pasos porque no hay compatibilidad para hacer la actualización hasta 2019. Podrías actualizar a 2012 y luego a 2019. Y antes de subir el nivel de compatibilidad de las bases de datos, activar el Query Store para revisar si hay problemas con el cambio de estimador de cardinalidad.

La otra opción es más sencilla. Instalas la instancia 2019, tomas un respaldo de la base de datos 2008 y lo restauras en la nueva instancia. Aplica la misma recomendación para el nivel de compatibilidad. Recuerda que en este caso, también tienes que asegurarte de que tienes los logins y roles configurados correctamente y asignados a los usuarios de las bases de datos.